# Accessing events on external drive in iMovie '11 on Lion

Tags: macos, hard-drive, imovie, nfs

I have my iMovie events stored on my external harddrive (located in a Synology NAS). It worked like a charm with iMovie '11 on Snow Leopard.

I then received my new MBP with Lion and the external drive is not showing. I cannot thus access my events which is pretty annoying as it prevents me from using the application...

<strike>Here is what I see in iMovie:</strike>(see edit 2 for new state)

<strike>I previously had my external drive below the Macintosh HD one.</strike>

My external drive is correctly mounted before launching iMovie:
[image: mounted HDD info]

It has the *iMovie Events* folder at root level (and as I said, it was correctly detected under same iMovie version on Snow Leopard).

I tried mounting it using afp: but result is the same.

Any help appreciated as I don't get what could have changed between SL and Lion for this.

---

edit: Same with volume now mounted using NFS:
[image: NFS Volume]

The list in iMovie stays desperately empty...

---

edit 2: something new!
My NFS mounts are now visible in the list (probably coming from an update of iMovie inbetween).
Problem is that they are still empty and with a yellow warning sign, without any tooltip on it...
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I did me a nice christmas gift by solving this, and quite easily in fact.
It could be considered as workaround only but it saved my life.

Answer: **symlink**!

Now, in my *Movies* folder, the *iMovie Events* folder is pointing to the *iMovie Events* folder I have on my external harddrive. All my videos are back and I can add videos without issue.

So waiting for the trick to get it work how it should, at least, I can use the application again!

Answer (score 1):

Lion turned off an older and less secure method of authenticating AFP connections, which a lot of third-party vendors of NAS devices were using, including Synology. Synology have made available a [beta release](http://www.synology.com/dsm/index_dsm3.2.php) of their new firmware which fully supports Lion (as long as your Synology device was made in 2008 or later).

Comment: Before posting I upgraded my NAS to the last 3.1 DSM version not seeing there were a 3.2 Beta. I'll try this one.

Comment: Upgraded to 3.2 beta and still the same issue. When mounted (afp or smb) drive is not showing up in iMovie... :(

Comment: Now upgraded to final 3.2 version for my NAS and still the same issue (afp, smb or nfs)