# Unable to mount an NFS share

Tags: macos, network, nfs

I'm trying to access my (Synology) NAS share through NFS and always get the same issue.

First, I activated NFS support in my NAS:
[image: NAS activated]

Then I set the permissions on the NAS:
[image: NAS NFS permissions]

My MBP has the IP 192.168.1.109.
From there it seems OK. a `showmount -e 192.168.1.2` shows the list:

`Exports list on 192.168.1.2:

/volume1/video                      192.168.1.109

/volume1/homes                      192.168.1.109`

But unfortunately, my mount always fails:

`GroundControl:/ ludo$ sudo mount -t nfs -o rw 192.168.1.2:/volume1/homes /Volumes/home

mount_nfs: can't mount /volume1/homes from 192.168.1.2 onto /Volumes/home: Operation not permitted`

The /Volume/home directory is created upfront.

Trying with a non-existing share on the NAS, for example */volume1/qwerty* gives a Permission denied error, which is OK.
But what is this Operation not permitted error?

Trying through *DiskUtils>NFS Mounts* gives the same result.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution in an [old forum thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=317044).

> My solution was to mount with "-P" to force the use of a reserved port number, as described in mount_nfs(8) page.

The solution is then to use the `-P` option to the `mount` command.
Now works like a charm (but doesn't fix my [initial issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/19423/1227)!)

Answer (score 5):

Or just use the "resvport" option with the `mount` command.

```
mount -o resvport nasbox.local.com:/try /mnt
```

Comment: That did it for me.