# Problem when copying files to NFS mounted disk (MacOS Catalina)

Tags: macos, catalina, nfs

I've mounted a Ubuntu NFS disk over my MacOS, but when I try to copy files from my disk to it, I start to recieve this errors. I've tried to use **ls** on the same file system on a Ubuntu 18.04, but the error doesn't appear there.

Does someone know what to do?

Using ls on a MacOS Catalina with **sudo**:
[image]

Using **ls** on Mac, no answer:
[image]

If I try to move files from my disk to the NFS, I got stuck (this process never ends)
[image]

But, if I try to use ls from a Ubuntu, I got no problems.

EDIT:
When I try to move files using terminal, I got this error:

```
~/Downloads: sudo mv tst ../Public 
nfs server 10.112.1.10:/storage/public: lockd not responding
```

Comment: Hello, ankii, thanks for your reply.
The outputs are just the files inside the folder. The point is that using ls, it get stucked. When I move files from Finder to this folder, get stucked too. When using sudo ls, I can see the files, but without sudo, I cannot. Don't know where to start.

Comment: Please [edit] the post :) I am just reading about this stuff for the first time. Can't help.  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142697/why-does-mounting-an-nfs-share-from-linux-require-the-use-of-a-privileged-port https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/292670/313842  Use the tag to search more questions. also, https://askubuntu.com and https://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Ok, I did the edit