# Best way of sharing files over network with linux

Tags: macos, unix, file-sharing

I have an iMac running Mac OS 10.7.3 which is connected to wifi network, there is also a linux laptop connected to the same network. I want to share a folder with this laptop, I cannot use ftp since it was removed from system preferences. I don't want to share everything, so remote login is not option, unless there are settings to restrict it, so what is the best way of sharing this folder?

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `File Sharing` option in the System Preferences.

It will give you the option to share using `AFP` or `SMB`, both of which are supported in Linux.

You didn't specify which Linux distribution you are using specifically, but most graphical distributions such as Ubuntu have `SMB` support out of the box (just go to Places->Network and find your share). `AFP` support can be obtained by installing [`afpfs-ng`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/afpfs-ng/).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to AFP, and SMB, both of which are reasonably non-unixy, you can also use NFS.

AFP also has issues in Lion with other OSs using netatalk libraries.

NFS is very well supported on Linux.

See this for a comparison: [NFS, AFP, SMB... Advantages and drawbacks on a Mac OS system](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19470/nfs-afp-smb-advantages-and-drawbacks-on-a-mac-os-system)