# NAS-drives for Lion

Tags: macos, backup, hardware, nas

I want to invest in an NAS drive for backup & I looked around on the internet to see what is available; I looked at NAS drives from most of the leading brands but most of them get bad reviews especially when the users run Lion.

Do you have any tips or suggestions so I can make a good choice & not end up trowing away my money or worse, loosing my data?

Comment: Hardware recommendation ("let's go shopping") questions are off-topic. Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Synology<sup>1</sup> frontpage is self-speaking:

[image]

I have a synology NAS. Always been happy with it, even if I ran into trouble when switching to Lion (see [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/19423/1227)). However, I don't know yet (help guys!) if it's linked to the NAS or not.
It's TimeMachine compatible, it can also act as an rsync server, supports AFP protocol as well as NFS. I don't know other brands so I will only speak for this one.

<sup>1- and no, I don't work for Synology, I'm just a happy user :)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The entire Promise line is solid. You'll want to look for NS models that are aimed/priced for home user / small office. None of my existing Promise drives has had any issues with Lion.

http://www.promise.com